# Is it possible to perform network analyses faceting per experimental condition using igraph in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I would like to perform network analyses using igraph package in R comparing edges and vertices between 2 different experimental conditions (A and B).
Is there a way to perform something similar to a facet function using igraph?

I generated vertice and edge dataframes containing duplicate vertices and edges (one per experimental condition).
Below I reported a short version of my data frames:

```
vertices<-data.frame(marker = c("CD3", "CD25", "pCREB", "CD4", "pSTAT5", "pS6", "pRB",  "CD25", "CD3", "pSTAT4"),
cond_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
EMD= c(-0.83, -1.43, -0.07, -1.16, 0.08, 0.16, 0.28, 1.83,-0.37, 0.12 )
)

edges<-data.frame(marker_x = c("CD3","CD3", "CD4", "pSTAT5", "pRB", "CD25", "CD3"),
                  marker_y = c("CD25", "pCREB", "CD25", "pS6", "pS6", "pS6", "pSTAT4"),
                  cond_1 = c("A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B"),
                  DREMI=c(0.53, 0.80, 0.7, 1, 0.35,0.24, 0.44)
)
```

So far, I only managed to run igraph splitting the dataframes considering 1 experimental condition (A or B) at a time as reported below.
Analysis of condition B:

```
#selected and run igraph for condition B
t<- unique(vertices$cond_1[vertices$cond_1 == "A"]) 
t
vertices2<-vertices[!vertices$cond_1 %in% t, ]

q<- unique(edges$cond_1[edges$cond_1 == "A"]) 
q
edges2<-edges[!edges$cond_1 %in% q, ]
g<-graph_from_data_frame(d=edges2, vertices=vertices2, directed=TRUE)
g

#weighted edges according to the numeric value DREMI
w1 <-E(g)$DREMI
#generated a gradient scale for vertices
my_resolution = 100
my_palette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 9, name= "Reds"), alpha=TRUE)
my_max    = max(V(g)$EMD, na.rm=TRUE)
my_vector = V(g)$EMD / my_max
my_colors = my_palette(my_resolution)[as.numeric(cut(my_vector, breaks=my_resolution))]
#generated a gradient scale for edges
my_resolutionE = 5
my_paletteE = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 5, name= "Blues"), alpha=TRUE)
my_maxE    = max(E(g)$DREMI, na.rm=TRUE)
my_vectorE = E(g)$DREMI / my_maxE
my_colorsE = my_paletteE(my_resolutionE)[as.numeric(cut(my_vectorE, breaks=my_resolutionE))]

plot(g, vertex.color=my_colors,
     layout = layout_nicely(g), 
     vertex.label.color ="black",
     edge.color = my_colorsE,
     edge.width = w1,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     vertex.size =15,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.5)
```

Analysis for condition A:

```
#selected and run igraph for condition A
w<- unique(vertices$cond_1[vertices$cond_1 == "B"]) 
w
vertices3<-vertices[!vertices$cond_1 %in% w, ]

r<- unique(edges$cond_1[edges$cond_1 == "B"]) 
r
edges3<-edges[!edges$cond_1 %in% r, ]
g3<-graph_from_data_frame(d=edges3, vertices=vertices3, directed=TRUE)
g3

#weighted edges according to the numeric value DREMI
w1 <-E(g3)$DREMI
#generated a gradient scale for vertices
my_resolution = 100
my_palette = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 9, name= "Reds"), alpha=TRUE)
my_max    = max(V(g3)$EMD, na.rm=TRUE)
my_vector = V(g3)$EMD / my_max
my_colors = my_palette(my_resolution)[as.numeric(cut(my_vector, breaks=my_resolution))]
#generated a gradient scale for edges
my_resolutionE = 5
my_paletteE = colorRampPalette(brewer.pal(n = 5, name= "Blues"), alpha=TRUE)
my_maxE    = max(E(g3)$DREMI, na.rm=TRUE)
my_vectorE = E(g3)$DREMI / my_maxE
my_colorsE = my_paletteE(my_resolutionE)[as.numeric(cut(my_vectorE, breaks=my_resolutionE))]

plot(g3, vertex.color=my_colors,
     layout = layout_nicely(g3), 
     vertex.label.color ="black",
     edge.color = my_colorsE,
     edge.width = w1,
     edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
     vertex.size =15,
     vertex.label.cex = 0.5)
```

In this way however I cannot directly compare the 2 conditions in terms of gradient colour scale of vertices and edges. I would like to plot A and B network analyses side by side with a common gradient colour scale for edges and vertices in the 2 conditions.

When I try to run my igraph using my entire data frames (not selecting one specific condition):

```
g0<-graph_from_data_frame(d=edges, vertices=vertices, directed=TRUE)
g0
```

I get this error:

```
Error in graph_from_data_frame(d = edges, vertices = vertices, directed = TRUE) : 
  Duplicate vertex names
```

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: Question is too broad, please provide example input data, expected output, current codes.

Comment: Thank you, I updated my post

Comment: Welcome to SO. Sharing pictures of your data is not too helpful, as we cannot work with it. You can either share (part of) your data using `dput`, or create some dummy data, so that all of your code is reproducible. See here for more info https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Many thanks for the advice, I updated my post

Answer (score 0):

I'm not super clear on what you want to achieve, but if I get it right, you want to be able to have both plots side by side so that you can compare them.

You could use `par()` to set the plots side by side like this.

```r
par(mfrow = c(1,2)) # graphical parameter function (you can tinker with what you
# need)

# plot g

plot(g, vertex.color=my_colors,
         layout = layout_nicely(g), 
         vertex.label.color ="black",
         edge.color = my_colorsE,
         edge.width = w1,
         edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
         vertex.size =15,
         vertex.label.cex = 0.5)

# plot g3

    plot(g3, vertex.color=my_colors,
             layout = layout_nicely(g3), 
             vertex.label.color ="black",
             edge.color = my_colorsE,
             edge.width = w1,
             edge.arrow.size = 0.5,
             vertex.size =15,
             vertex.label.cex = 0.5)
```

[image]

I know that `ggraph` has a `facet_graph()` function that operates similarly to that found in `ggplot`--and that might be another solution.